# Is hitchhiking on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is hitchhiking on topic, or should I ask such questions at the travel-site? For me it is somehow outdoor-related, because I often travel this way to my starting points, druing the trip or back home, but I guess that´s not a typical association.

Comment: Also see http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/395/is-asking-about-shuttle-services-for-trail-heads-off-topic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think some aspects of hitch-hiking are certainly on-topic.  Hitch-hiking is typically an activity in rural/natural areas, as opposed to urban ones.  To be on the safe side you might want to bring a tent/bivouac, in case you don't get any ride by nightfall.  Personally, I think it should be on-topic.

**However**, I think it is more specifically on-topic on Travel, and think you should expect better answers there, unless the questions are specifically on how to survive in outdoor conditions while waiting for your hitch.

Answer (score 7):

From a US perspective, many thru-hikers on trails like the Appalachian or Pacific Crest Trails use hitch-hiking to make their way to and from towns for re-supply.  (I suspect this is one of the few remaining circumstances in which Americans might regularly hitch-hike.)  In this context posting to the outdoor forum is likely to garner more relevant answers, as the practice is both integral to the outdoor activity of thru-hiking and likely used mainly by such hikers.  In regions where hitch-hiking is more common I suspect the travel forum may be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good point. I also used it for restocking on several occasions, especially during group hike where to people would by some supplies a little of the trail.